# XSLT: combining attribute values

Tags: xml, xslt

I am looking to combine the same attribute from two or more ancestor tags into the tag I am matching in my template.

Example input:

```
<tag1 indent="up2">
    <tag2 indent="up1">
        <tag3></tag3>
    </tag2>
</tag1>
```

Example output:

```
<tag1 indent="up2">
    <tag2 indent="up1">
        <tag3 indent="up3"></tag3>
    </tag2>
</tag1>
```

So basically, I am looking for child tags to inherit the indent from their ancestors- there could also be other levels(the number of levels could change). There could also be "down" tags.

What I thought about doing is replacing the "up" with a "+" and then "down" with a "-", doing the mathematical operation and then putting it in.

Comment: replacing "up" with "+" and replacing "down" with "-" should produce "+2" and "+1"- adding those two together will be "+3", since it's a positive number it will be an "up". If the two values were "down5" and "up1" it would be "-5" and "+1", which would make "-4" which would turn into "down4"

Comment: What have you tried so far? How many levels would be imbricated in the input XML?

Comment: what I am trying right now is:
    <xsl:variable name="indentcount" select="./ancestor::*[@indent]/@indent"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="./ancestor::*[@indent]/@indent">
        <xsl:attribute name="indent" select="$indentcount"/>
    </xsl:for-each>

and then I try to replace the "up" and "down" in the select in the attribute tag but I get an error saying there are too many items.

Comment: @user2183943 Please indicate if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: ok, so I got it to be a string of "+2+1", how do I change that string to a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*[@indent]">
    <xsl:param name="prev-indent" select="0"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
            <xsl:with-param name="prev-indent" select="translate($prev-indent, 'dupown', '-') + translate(@indent, 'dupown', '-')" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:param name="prev-indent" select="0"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="indent">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$prev-indent &lt; 0">
                    <xsl:text>down</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="-$prev-indent" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>up</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$prev-indent" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit:

Since you're using XSLT 2.0, you could simplify this to:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(@indent)]">
    <xsl:variable name="indent" select="sum(ancestor::*/number(translate(@indent, 'dupown', '-')))" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="indent" select="concat(if ($indent lt 0) then 'down' else 'up', abs($indent))"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This returns "upNaN" where I ran it, I think because "number()" only allows one "+/-" and then digits when it's a string. It does not allow multiple "+" or "-" in the string. So I need to handle the mathematical operation in the string elsewhere. 

This is ok "number(+3+5+5)" as is this "number('+3')" but "number('+3+5')" is not

Comment: I ran it with the example given in your question (as well as others) and it returns the expected results.There are no multiple "+" in the string. In fact, there is no string at all (that would be a dead end). The expression sums the nodes after converting them (individually) to numbers by removing the text and adding a negative sign where necessary.

Comment: Thanks for you help. The example I gave was only an example of the type of code I am working with. I can't share the actual code. There must be something different, because it won't work.

Comment: Yeah well, we can only work with what you give us. I cannot adjust it to something I cannot see.

Comment: I think I got it using your solution-- I had to change it to include [@indent]  after the "::*" because not every level has an indent, so need to add only the ones that do. The ones that don't were giving it "NaN"